# Is it possible to subclass UIPanGestureRecognizer to have it's begin state occur after some distance threshold has been reached

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to subclass `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so that in my subclass the state changes to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` only after some distance threshold has been reached during panning. That means after some amount of panning I'd like the state of the pan gesture to become `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

I tried plugging into `touchesBegan` and set the state manually to failed and then in `touchesMoved` updated it to begin but I only want to change it to begin one time (i.e. the first time that it reaches the threshold and then subsequent interactions would be `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`

Is this possible?

Comment: On another note, you could just calculate the pan progress (in a scale of 0.0~1.0) and compare with the threshold value in the `.changed` state. And do your job accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought as well but we probably can't rely on converting to `began` state so we'd have to introduce more state in the gesture with boolean conditionals to find if the threshold has been reached. Ideally I'd just want to prevent the began state from being called

Answer (score 1):

Here's a subclass that seems to work. It delays the "began" state until a desired distance is met.

DelayedPanGestureRecognizer.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DelayedPanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat delay;

@end
```

DelayedPanGestureRecognizer.m:

```
#import "DelayedPanGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation DelayedPanGestureRecognizer

- (void)setState:(UIGestureRecognizerState)state {
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint trans = [self translationInView:self.view];
        if (trans.x * trans.x + trans.y * trans.y > self.delay * self.delay) {
            [super setState:state];
        }
    } else {
        [super setState:state];
    }
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
DelayedPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[DelayedPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panned:)];
pan.delay = 6;
[someView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And the action:

```
- (void)panned:(DelayedPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"State: %d", (int)gesture.state);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([gesture translationInView:gesture.view]));

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureStateBegan) {
        // do something
    } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureStateChanged) {
        // do other things
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as I expected. It looks like you're multiplying the y translations: `trans.y * trans.y` for one so the delay is not a linear translation threhsold but rather a multiplied / exponential threshold. Also it looks like the `UIGestureStateBegan` is only set once so it only takes the translation from the first pan up.

Comment: I had a typo. The `if` is using a simple Pythagorean theorem for a right triangle. And yes, `UIGestureStateBegan` is set once. That's how it is even without this code. This code just delays when the `UIGestureStateBegan` state is sent. This code works just fine for me in a test iOS app I wrote. You just need to set `delay` to whatever distance you want.

Comment: Not quite, this conditional: if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) is only hit once. When you initially start the gesture. At that point the translation is very small. I'd like to see if the threshold is crossed when the user holds and keeps panning up. At the moment that happens I'd like to invoke some method

Comment: Did you actually try using this custom recognizer? It does what you want. Apply this `DelayedPanGestureRecognizer` to your view. Set a desired delay. In your action method, check the state. You will get the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` state just once (as normal) but only after you have panned enough. Then you will get all of the normal `Changed` events. I update the answer with an example.

Comment: Yeah I've added this code to my custom pan gesture but it looks like the state is only initialized once and therefore `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` is only called once. More concretely I've added a log function in the state if it's began `if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"translation y");
    }` I see that translationY is logged only once at the start. This is an issue as the caller `if (gesture.state == UIGestureStateBegan) {
        // do something
    } ` is only invoked if it's began and if in the first pan translation it moves the distance.

Comment: The `Began` state is only supposed to called once per pan. That's how a pan gesture works. If you touch, drag a bunch, and lift, you will get one "began", a bunch of "changed", and an "ended". If you press, drag, and lift again, you will get the same sequence again. The only difference with this custom gesture is that the "began" state isn't sent to the target until the drag moves more than normal. This is what you said you wanted. Don't add code to the `setState` override. The code that you wanted to behave differently is the action of your gesture.

Comment: "the "began" state isn't sent to the target until the drag moves more than normal." The began state is activated after the pan gesture moves the default pan gesture threshold value which is `10`. Then this method gets called. The Began state only happens once. Every subsequent state that gets passed is the Changed state. The problem is when you press, drag and lift again the began is really only called on `press` rather than on drag. The amount of distance you've traversed in the press is the threshold that first invokes it. Even in the code you provided the drag does not count the threshold

Comment: Do you have a sample project that illustrates your example? As I don't think the sample code should work as is right now

Comment: The code in my answer is everything I had in the sample project. Just create a new single view iOS project. Add the class for the custom gesture. Use the code under "usage" above in the `viewDidLoad` of the one view controller but add the gesture to `self.view`. Add the `panned` method to the view controller. That's all I did. I'm seeing the logs as expected. It's certainly possible I'm misunderstanding your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
// called when a gesture recognizer attempts to transition out of UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible. returning NO causes it to transition to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

Just return NO, Before you meet the conditions.